# React: How to avoid performance problem when uploading images to Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, react-hooks, cloudinary

I wrote a code that works but it's not a masterpiece. It has huge performance problems. How would I deal with it?

**Problems**

I have problems with the performance of my component:

1. Sending multiple images is very slow, when I send 5 pictures, it takes about 1-2 minutes.
2. How could I make sure that the photos are only uploaded to Cloudinary during the submission?
   Because, for example, when a user chooses photo A and then takes a look around and chooses photo B, photos A and B are uploaded to the cloud.

**Questions**

Would it be a good idea to disable the button for adding an album while transferring files to Cloudinary?

Please help me to solve these two problems and I want to make sure that the application works smoothly. Thank you so much.

```
const AddAlbum = () => {

  const [fileUrl, setFileUrl] = useState();

  // MultipleFiles
  const [multipleFileUrl, setMultipleFileUrl] = useState([]);
 
  // cloudnary upload api endpoint
  const api_cloudinary =
    "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/cloudinary_name/image/upload";

  
  // file upload
  const handleSingleFileUpload = async (files) => {
  

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", files[0]);
    formData.append("upload_preset", "preset_number");
    // send cloudinary image and presets info
    const res = await fetch(api_cloudinary, {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });

    const file = await res.json();
    console.log(file);
    const fileUrl = await file.eager[0].url;
    setFileUrl(fileUrl);
  };
  console.log(fileUrl);
  // upload many files cloudnary
  // For now max amount of files is 20
  const handleMultipleFileUpload = async (files, amount) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    for (let i = 0; i <= files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("upload_preset", ""preset_number"");

      const res = await fetch(api_cloudinary, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
      });

      const cloudinaryFiles = await res.json();
      console.log(cloudinaryFiles);
      setMultipleFileUrl(cloudinaryFiles);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(
      `
      Album name:${albumName}
      color:${color}
      Background Image: ${fileUrl}
      files:${multipleFileUrl}
      `
    );
  };
```

And forms

```
 return (
    <Wrapper>
    
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
       
    
        <div>
          <StyledLabel>Upload background image</StyledLabel>
          <DefaultInput
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => handleSingleFileUpload(e.target.files)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <StyledLabel>Upload background image</StyledLabel>
          <DefaultInput
            type="file"
            onChange={(e) => handleMultipleFileUpload(e.target.files)}
            multiple
          />
        </div>
       
        
        <StyledButton type="submit">Submit</StyledButton>
      </form>
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need 1 function to process 1 or more image files. You need to get the contents of each file and load the contents of the file into form data. Sample code is using the browser FileReader API to read the contents of local image files.  Look at this code in repl.it that is using vanilla JS. If it makes sense, you can fit it in to your framework.  Let me know if there are questions. https://repl.it/@rpeltz/fe-upload#script.js

```
  reader.addEventListener(
      "load", function () {
        const fileContents = reader.result;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a library that handles this for you. There are many edge cases that you need to take care of when dealing with file uploads.

[react-uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady) for example does this for you. so its easy as this:

```js
import React from "react";
import Uploady from "@rpldy/uploady";
import UploadButton from "@rpldy/upload-button";

const CLOUD_NAME = "<your-cloud-name>";
const UPLOAD_PRESET = "<your-upload-preset>";

const App = () => (<Uploady
    destination={{ 
        url: `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${CLOUD_NAME}/upload`,
        params: {
            upload_preset: UPLOAD_PRESET,
        }
    }}>
    <UploadButton/>
</Uploady>);
```

For production code, where you dont want to allow unsigned uploads, I recommend looking at this [guide](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady/blob/master/guides/Cloudinary.md#production)